# pyqt timer does not return a value or an error

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, functools

I am trying to use a timer with pyqt.  The code is below, but it does not print anything and I do not get an error.   Does anyone know what is wrong?
Thanks

```
import functools
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer

def onTimer(initParams):
    print initParams
    print "HERE"
    # your code here...
def update():
    print "Upd"
myInitParams = "Init!"
timerCallback = functools.partial(onTimer, myInitParams)
myTimer = QTimer()
myTimer.timeout.connect(timerCallback)
myTimer.start(1000) #once a sec

t = QTimer()

t.start(500)
t.timeout.connect(update)
```

EDIT UPDATE:

So this is a snip of the full code im using, which is a bit more complicated and maybe is a different problem, but the result is the same.

The structure is like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
# Import the UI Classes from the ui directory in this package
from ui.MoAnGUI import Ui_MoAnWindow

class MoAnWin(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_MoAnWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MoAnWin, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.playMarkers.clicked.connect(self._PlayMarkers)
        self.connect(self,QtCore.SIGNAL("PlayMarker"),PlayMarkerCall)
        #Marker Stop
        self.stopMarkers.clicked.connect(self._StopMarkers)
        self.connect(self,QtCore.SIGNAL("StopMarker"),StopMarkerCall)

    def _StopMarkers(self):
        arg = "Stop"
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("StopMarker"),arg)
    def _PlayMarkers(self):
        fps = self.fpsBox.value()
        starttime = self.fromTime.value()
        endtime = self.ToTime.value()
        arg = [fps,starttime,endtime]
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("PlayMarker"),arg)

def StopMarkerCall(arg):
    #I want to stop the timer here

def PlayMarkerCall(arg):

    #I tried this, but again, nothing happens, no error
    myInitParams = "Init!"
    timerCallback = functools.partial(TimerCall, myInitParams)
    myTimer = QtCore.QTimer()
    myTimer.timeout.connect(timerCallback)
    myTimer.start(1000) #once a sec

    #I Imagine something like this:
    myTimer = QtCore.QTimer()
    for i in range(start,end):
         # I want to connect to my view marker function but i need to pass a variable
         myTimer.timeout.connect(ViewMarkerCall(i))
         myTimer.start(1000)
def TimerCall(args):
    print "HERE", args

def show():
    global globalMoAnWindow
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    globalMoAnWindow = MoAnWin()
    globalMoAnWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    return globalMoAnWindow

show()
```

My goal is to have a button click play, and stuff happens in a qtgraphic widget at a certain time interval, then the stop button stops the playing.  I found the functools from another question on here, but im not sure if its the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correctly use Qt, you need to set up a `QtGui.QApplication` or `QtCore.QCoreApplication` and use it's event loop to process events.

This should work:

```
#from utils import sigint

import functools
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer, QCoreApplication
app = QCoreApplication([])

def onTimer(initParams):
    print initParams
    print "HERE"
    # your code here...
def update():
    print "Upd"
myInitParams = "Init!"
timerCallback = functools.partial(onTimer, myInitParams)
myTimer = QTimer()
myTimer.timeout.connect(timerCallback)
myTimer.start(1000) #once a sec

t = QTimer()

t.start(500)
t.timeout.connect(update)

# use a timer to stop the event loop after some time
stopTimer = QTimer(timeout=app.quit, singleShot=True)
stopTimer.start(4000)

app.exec_()
```

Edit:

In your updated version you don't keep any reference to your timer object you create in the `PlayMarkerCall` method. When `myTimer` goes out of scope, it is destroyed (together with the underlying C++ Qt object), that's why your timer never fires. 
And you can't pass parameters when you connect a signal to a slots, at that time you only set up the connection. Parameters can only be passed when the signal is emitted, to do that you could create a class derived from `QTimer` and override it's `timerEvent` method to emit a signal with arguments specified when instantiating the Timer.

Comment: I was trying to make the question simple, and didnt realize taking it out of the app broke it.  I updated my question to get at the problem in implementation.  could you help with that?

Comment: thank you, defining myTimer in the global scope made it do something.  Ill probably need to ask some questions later but this helped me alot for now!